# ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes ERROR Invariant Violation

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-auth

Estoy creando una autenticacion de login y registro en react native con expo, usando firebase pero me manda  los siguientes errores al correrlo

ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes      ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can ponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

este es mi archivo app.js:

```
// Importa los componentes necesarios de React Native
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import { auth } from "./firebaseconf";


function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>HomeScreen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

function LoginScreen () {
  
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  
  
  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try{
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    
      console.log('Sign In')
    }catch (e){
      console.log(e)
    }
      };

  // Función para manejar el registro
  const handleSignup = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try{
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    
      console.log('Account Created')
    
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e)
   
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Mi App</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Correo electrónico"
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
        value={email}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Contraseña"
        secureTextEntry
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        value={password}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleLogin}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Iniciar sesión</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleSignup}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Registrarse</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  return (<LoginScreen></LoginScreen>);
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  input: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 50,
    borderColor: "#ccc",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  button: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    borderRadius: 5,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```

y este es en el que tengo guardada la configuracion de firebase:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import * as firebase from "firebase";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...........",
  authDomain: ".................",
  projectId: "............,
  storageBucket: "............",
  messagingSenderId: ".........",
  appId: "......................"
};

const fire = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = fire.auth()

  export {auth}
// Initialize Firebase
```

ya he intentado varias soluciones que he encontrado pero ninguna funciono, agradeceria muchisimo su ayuda